# Is binding ToConstant and calling InSingletonScope redundant?

Tags: c#, ninject

Well, this question is pretty simply stated by the title.

For a local variable `factory`:

```
var factory = Fluently.Configure()
...
```

Are these two lines equivalent:

```
Bind<ISessionFactory>().ToConstant(factory).InSingletonScope();
```

and:

```
Bind<ISessionFactory>().ToConstant(factory);
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In the latest version of ninject, when you create a ToConstant binding it will automatically set the Scope to Singleton. Thus, the `InSingletonScope()` part in your example is redundant. From ninject code base:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Indicates that the service should be bound to the specified constant value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The constant value.</param>
    public IBindingWhenInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<T> ToConstant(T value)
    {
        Binding.ProviderCallback = ctx => new ConstantProvider<T>(value);
        Binding.Target = BindingTarget.Constant;
        Binding.ScopeCallback = StandardScopeCallbacks.Singleton;

        return this;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for digging into the code for me :) I'm using 2.2.1.2 (newest from NuGet) which does not have the `Binding.ScopeCallback` assignment. Is that just for internal houskeeping or does that mean I'll still need to specify `InSingletonScope` until we update to the latest version?

Comment: My opinion is that you better specify it explicitly in any case. It makes your intention more clear and protects you if default changes.

Comment: I do agree about being explicit, but I think binding to a "Constant" quite explicit describes my intention for that exact instance of an object to be the only result to this binding. The only semantic difference I can see with `InSingletonScope`, perhaps with an `OnActivate` callback for setup, is that the instance won't be created until the point that a request for the type in the binding is fulfilled.

Comment: Scope affects caching and activation. While net effect for `ToConstant` *seems* to be the same regardless, if you do performance tests, for example, you'll notice that there maybe difference between `InSingletonScope` and `InTransientScope` because caching code being executed is different.